# Command line tool for extracting .exe files

Tags: windows

I have an .exe file which is actually archive and I need to extract it in command line in unattended way to be able to further automate the installation of a program it "installs".

So my question is what command line archive tool can do it? As it seems that winzip's one can't.

Answer (score 1):

You will find most people would recommend [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)'s command line tool for this.

See here for the [command line tool usage](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).